# Get multi-class confusion matrix equal to number of class labels

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, confusion-matrix

I trained Random Forest Classifier in `sklearn` to predict multi-class classification problem.

My dataset has four class labels. But my code create 2x2 confusion matrix

```
y_predict = rf.predict(X_test)
conf_mat = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predict)
print(conf_mat)
```

Output:

```
[[0,   0]

 [394, 39]]
```

How can I get 4x4 confusion matrix to analyze TP, TN, FP, FN.

Comment: Depends on your `y_test`. Does your `y_test` contain all 4 labels or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation at 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

```
y_true = ["cat", "ant", "cat", "cat", "ant", "bird"]
y_pred = ["ant", "ant", "cat", "cat", "ant", "cat"]
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=["ant", "bird", "cat"])
```

Result :

```
array([[2, 0, 0], 
       [0, 0, 1], 
       [1, 0, 2]])
```